# Add category without removing existing categories

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro that checks email for an attachment and assigns a category. I need to keep the existing categories. It currently removes any old ones.

```
Sub Categories()

If Item.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

Dim attCount As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim sFileType As String

Set attCount = Item.Attachments.Count

For i = attCount To 1 Step -1

  strFile = Item.Attachments.Item(i).FileName       
  sFileType = LCase$(Right$(strFile, 4))

Select Case sFileType
    Case ".wwb", ".sdd"
' do something if the file types are found
' this code assigns a cateogry to the message
  Item.Categories = "WWB"
  Item.Save

' stop checking if a match is found and exit sub
   GoTo endsub
  End Select
  Next i

  End If

  endsub:

  Set Item = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Item.Categories = Item.Categories & "," & "WWB"
```